# Overview map openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using openlayers to display 3 layers, a google base layer, and 2 layers that i call from Geoserver. The projection i am using is EPSG:3857. 
My problem is ......
My overview map location does not tally with the location on my main map. So for instance if i scroll on my main map to north Africa, my overview map shows Australia. The overview map moves when the main map moves but the location is completely different. I tried all sorts of code but i cannot solve the problem.
Does anyone know how i can solve my problem? 
One of my codes is below....

```
map.addControl(
    new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap({
        autoPan:true,
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(10264212.20144042, -1368478.0758595483, 17758023.6939145, 3318388.9003530084),
        restrictExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(10264212.20144042, -1368478.0758595483, 17758023.6939145, 3318388.9003530084),
        maxResolution: 29272.70114247687,
        //projection: "EPSG:3857",
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
        units: 'm',
        numZoomLevels: 5
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The OverviewMap control doesn't have some of the properties like maxExtent, projection, etc. But the problem may not be here in the OverviewMap control. Can you put more codes here? especially those how you initialize the map instance and layer instances.

One error-prone place I can think of now is about the spherical mercator projection and the alias. You may need to assign explicitly the EPSG:3857 projection to the google base layer. You can get more information [here](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html#sphericalmercator-and-epsg-aliases).